# Route mail to POP Server

Tags: exchange, outlook

We have an exchange server 2003 running locally.
When Staff A sends mail to Staff B, the server just delivers it locally.
When staff A sends mail to an external email address, the server sends it to our cloud server, which then forwards to the destination.

Each staff has an account in the cloud server, and also an exchange account.

Users can access their webmail for the cloud account (tho they only seen mails from external sources)

Problem is, I want a situation where Staff A sends a mail to Staff B, the exchange server delivers it locally, and also delivers to the POP cloud server

Comment: Is this something you want for all your staff, or only for a specific recipient?

Comment: a certain few. Most dont need it because they are fine with the current setup. others who are very mobile and access the webmail more often need this

Comment: Your setup doesn't make sense to me. Why do you have an Exchange server and a "cloud" server? Why don't you just use Exchange server the way it's meant to be used?

Comment: the exchange server pulls mails from the cloud POP server